# How to get 2 strings separated by a dash?

Tags: javascript

In a project I got IDs consisting of two parts, The parts are separated by a dash. How can I get part 1 and part 2?

JS

```
var ID = "100-200";

var id_part1 = 0;
var id_part2 = 0;
```

Comment: You can use `split`(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) for this

Comment: OP, no-one's said explicitly but `str.split()` produces an _array_. You can access the elements using the indexes as shown in the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    var id = "100-200";
    var arr = id.split("-");
    alert(arr[0]);
    alert(arr[1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

With simple `JavaScript`:

```
ID = "100-200";
var values = ID.split('-');

var id_part1 = values[0];
var id_part2 = values[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = "100-200";
var array = id.split("-");
var id_part1 = array[0];
var id_part2 = array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp): Try this

```
var str = "100-200";
var res = str.split("-");
```

Result is in array list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var ID= "100-200" ;
ID=ID.split('-')[1];
var id_part1 = ID[0];
var id_part2 = ID[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be done in one line with the destructuring assignment:

```js
var ID = "100-200";
var [id_part1, id_part2] = ID.split('-');

console.log('id_part1: ', id_part1);
console.log('id_part2: ', id_part2);
```